# Discretization of forward gradient and (backward) divergence with Dirichlet or Neumann

Tags: numerical-methods

I want to refer to Equation. (10) in http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2014/103/ .

We consider one dimension and the vector $u\in \mathbb R^n$. For simplicity, we choose $n=3$.

### Neumann boundary condition

If we assume the Neumann boundary condition $\nabla u=0$ when $x\in \partial\Omega$, the discrete forward differential operator $D$ is as follows:

$$ D =  \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & \\ & -1 & 1 \\ & & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$Du = \begin{cases} u_{i+1} - u_{i} & \text{if}  &i < n \\
0 & \text{if}  &i=n  \end{cases} $$

Then, the discrete divergence operator is defined by
$$ -D^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & & \\ -1 & 1 & \\ & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

to satisfy the condition that the divergence operator is the adjoint of the gradient operator.

$$-D^T (x) = \begin{cases}
u_1 & \text{if}  &i=1  \\ u_{i} - u_{i-1} & \text{if}  &1 < i < n \\
-u_{i-1} & \text{if}  &i=n  \end{cases} $$

### Dirichlet boundary condition

If we assume that the Dirichlet boundary condition $u(n+1)=0$,
the discrete forward differential operator $D$ is as follows:

$$ D =  \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & \\ & -1 & 1 \\ & & -1 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$Du = \begin{cases} u_{i+1} - u_{i} & \text{if}  &i < n \\
-u_i & \text{if}  &i=n  \end{cases} $$

Then, the discrete divergence operator is defined by
$$ -D^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & & \\ -1 & 1 & \\ & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$-D^T (x) = \begin{cases}
u_1 & \text{if}  &i=1  \\ u_{i} - u_{i-1} & \text{if}  &1 < i < n \\
u_{i}-u_{i-1} & \text{if}  &i=n  \end{cases} $$

---

My first question is that *Am I right until this?* . Because my numerical result seems wrong if I choose Dirichlet boundary condition.

My second question is that if $u(n+1)=v$, how to discretize?